# Auto-playing embed code issue in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to automatically play the .swf file when the page load in word-press
This is my embadded code:

```
<embed src="http://turkchat.nl/newturkchat/turkchat/wp-content/themes/rt_oculus_wp/swf/Ov1.swf"
   type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="358" height="240" align="middle" 
   name="Ov1/Ov1" autoPlay="1"></embed>
```

Video is showing but **not** automatically playing.

Comment: <embed src="http://turkchat.nl/newturkchat/turkchat/wp-content/themes/rt_oculus_wp/swf/Ov1.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="358" height="240" align="middle" name="Ov1/Ov1" autoPlay="1"></embed>     This is my embed code

Answer (score 0):

Add  "autoPlay=true" as a parameter this should work. instead of autoPlay=1.